# What is the difference when parsing between Tab and Spaces in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have encountered a scenario below

```
Declare @var int = '       123'  
select @var

Declare @var1 int = '      123'  
select @var1
```

for the first case I have used spaces in front of the value and while execute it returns value as 123

In Second case I have used tab instead of space in front of value and while execute it throws conversion error

Can anyone let know what is the difference between these 2 scenario..

Comment: I think you have observed the difference.  Spaces are ignored, but tabs are not.

Comment: Your code *parses* the string to get an integer. It's equivalent to `Declare @var int =cast( '       123' as int)`. In SQL, spaces can be ignored. Tabs can't. SQL, the language, has some rather interesting quirks regarding leading/trailing spaces. You should use explicit parsing to avoid such surprises

Comment: They are different characters. A tab has the ascii code `9` and a space `32`. They differ visually as well (a tab is usually the width of 4 spaces). Just like any other character, `tab` and `space`are not the same.

Comment: @Larnu note that the OP is assigning to an `int` variable. This is more about implicit parsing than character differences

Comment: Thank You @GordonLinoff   for your answer and valuable time to answer me

Comment: Thank You @PanagiotisKanavos   for your answer and valuable time to answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have put same number of spaces (using spaces and then Tab) the character codes for both of them is different and that is the reason that space and TAB are treated as separately in SQL Server.

More information about character codes and character encoding can be found at below 2 links:-

https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/charcode.htm
https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/51983/standards-character-codes

Also if you think mathematically and logically:- having spaces before integer numbers does not make sense. It's like having zeros before numbers. 
For Example:-'     123' (5 spaces and then 123) is like 00000123. 
Yet one more reason that spaces are trimmed before the integer numbers

Comment: Best Example for my above answer:- I had actually given 5 spaces before '123' but stackoverflow too omitted the extra spaces.